# Angular Materials Cards Layout Issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to position two cards next to each other.

The card on the left has `display: flex` so I can centre the contents of it.

I can't figure out how to make the next card, sit next to it without making the card on the left `inline-block` also.

Here is the `initials component` with the details component.

```
<mat-card class="card card-initials">
    <span>BD</span>
</mat-card>

<details-component></details-component>
```

Here is the CSS for that component.

```
.card{
    padding: 0;
    width: 225px;
    margin: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

.card-initials {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: #D3DCE5;
    border-bottom: #afbfd0 1px solid;
}

.card-initials span {
    text-align: center;
    width: inherit;
    line-height: 225px;
    font-size: 72px;
}
```

Here is the details component, where I plan to have two cards, adjacent to the initials component.

```
<mat-card>
    Personal Info
</mat-card>
```

Not sure what display properties to put on that.

Here is how it looks currently,

[image]

Here is how I would like it to look, so you get a better idea of what I'm aiming for:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `@angular/flex-layout` or Twitter - Bootstrap to manage layout and flex-boxes? The following uses `@angular/flex-layout` to create to columns and two rows in the right column: <div fxLayout="row"><mat-card>BD</mat-card><details-component></details-component></div>, and in the details component: <div fxLayout="column"><mat-card>Card 1</mat-card><mat-card>Card 2</mat-card></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular flex-layout.

Wrap a `div` around your cards, with `fxLayout="row"`:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div>
    <mat-card class="card card-initials">
      <span>BD</span>
    </mat-card>
    <details-component></details-component>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="column">
    <mat-card>details box 1</mat-card>
    <mat-card>details box 2</mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be doing the same thing still, as in the first image. Where it is beneath and not adjacent to it.

Comment: Do you want the "Personal Info" box underneath the initials, or beside them?

Comment: That personal info box is meant to be the details box. Sorry, should have made that clearer.